# Amortization Formula：$B_{t+1}=B_t\cdot (1+i)-R$ .Why is this established?

Tags: actuarial-science

According to the book,The theory of interest,
at page 158, I found this formula:
$$B_{t+1}=B_t\cdot (1+i)-R,$$

while $B_t$ means the outstanding balance at time $t$ and $R$ means the installment payment at the end of each period.
I don't get why this formula is established......

Comment: This is hard to read..  Of course the interest payment due at time $t+1$ is $i\times B_t$, with an appropriate definition of the interest rate $i$.  And of course the rest of the coupon payment is made up by Balance reduction.  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Do you mean $B_{t+1}=B_t(1+i)-R$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you take out a loan of $B_0$ at $t=0$ (present) and you repay a constant installment $R$ every year. And let denote the yearly nominal interest rate as $i$. On one hand in one year the outstanding loan increase by $B_0\cdot i$. Consequently the loan increase to $B_0+B_0\cdot i= (1+i)\cdot B_0$. On the other hand you repay the installment R (at the end of the year).

Thus the outstanding loan at $t=1$ is $B_1=(1+i)\cdot B_0-R$. The recurrence equation can be written for $t=2, t=3, ...$

$B_1=(1+i)\cdot B_0-R \quad (1)$

$B_2=(1+i)\cdot B_1-R \quad (2)$

$B_3=(1+i)\cdot B_2-R \quad (3)$

$\vdots$

You can use the term for $B_1$ from the first equation and insert it in the second equation.

$B_2=(1+i)\cdot ((1+i)\cdot B_0-R)-R=B_0\cdot (1+i)^2-R\cdot (1+i)-R$

Next use the term for $B_2$ from the second equation and insert it in the third equation.

$B_3=(1+i)\cdot (B_0\cdot (1+i)^2-R\cdot (1+i)-R)-R$

$=B_0\cdot (1+i)^3-R\cdot (1+i)^2-R\cdot (1+i)-R =B_0\cdot (1+i)^3-R\cdot \left(1+(1+i)+(1+i)^2 \right)$

A pattern can be observed and we can generalize it to an arbitrary year $t$.

$B_t=B_0\cdot (1+i)^t-R\cdot \left(\color{blue}{1+(1+i)+(1+i)^2+\ldots +(1+i)^{t-1}} \right)$

The blue term is a finite $\textrm{geometric series}$ [[1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1575759/max-price-of-a-share/1576476#1576476)] which has a closed form: $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{t-1} x^i=\frac{x^t-1}{x-1}$. Thus $B_t$ can be simplified to

$$B_t=B_0\cdot (1+i)^k-R\cdot \frac{(1+i)^t-1}{(1+i)-1}=B_0\cdot (1+i)^t-R\cdot \frac{(1+i)^t-1}{i}$$

I hope I was able to clarify some questions. If something is unclear, feel free to ask.

Comment: Thank you so so so much.It's very clear!

Comment: Rhat pleases me. You're welcome.